# Overloading == operator for template results in unknown address error/

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the `==` operator for a class `Structure`, which is a multi-type container. My approach for other operations has been to have an empty virtual function in the `Structure` class and override it in the derived `Element` template class.

This is because, when adding the elements to the vector, I am wrapping them into `Element` and storing them in the vector as `StructPtrs`. In order to know the type of each `StructPtr`, I must do the above (I cannot use `dynamic_cast`) because it will only know its type when it calls on the overridden function in the `Element` class.

```
class Structure;
using StructPtr = std::shared_ptr<Structure>;

template<class T>
class Element;

// Make sure to define your printElement function, too.
void printElement(std::ostream& out, const Structure& s);

// Define your `Structure` class here
class Structure{
public:
    Structure() = default;
    virtual ~Structure() = default;

    Structure(const Structure& oldStruct){
        for(auto element : oldStruct.elements)
            elements.emplace_back(element->getCopy());
    }

    Structure operator = (const Structure& otherStruct){
        if(this == &otherStruct)
            return *this;
        if(elements.size() != otherStruct.elements.size()){
            elements.clear();
        }
        std::copy(otherStruct.elements.begin(), otherStruct.elements.end(), std::back_inserter(elements));
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator == (const Structure& other) const{
        if(elements.empty() && other.elements.empty())
            return true;
        bool result = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < other.elements.size(); i++){
            if(elements[i]->equals(*(other.elements[i])))
                result = true;
            else result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    virtual bool equals( Structure& otherStruct) const { }

    template<class T>
    void add(T obj){
        elements.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Element<T>>(obj));
    }

    virtual StructPtr getCopy() const {}

    virtual void printDerived(std::ostream& out) const{}

    void print(std::ostream& out) const{
        for(auto element : elements)
            element->printDerived(out);
    }

    std::vector<StructPtr> elements;
};

template<class T>
class Element : public Structure{
public:
    Element() = default;
    //Element(int element) : element(element) { }
    //Element(Structure element) : element(element) { }
    //Element(std::string element) : element(element) { }
    Element(T _element) : element(_element) { }
    Element( const Element<T>& oldElement){
        element = oldElement.element;
    }

    bool equals ( Structure& otherStruct) const override{
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Structure>){
            return element == otherStruct; 
        }
        auto other = static_cast<Element&>(otherStruct);
        return element == other.element;   
    }

    StructPtr getCopy() const override {
        StructPtr newStructPtr;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Structure>){
            Structure newStruct(*this);
            newStructPtr = std::make_shared<Element<T>>(newStruct);
        }
        else 
            newStructPtr = std::make_shared<Element<T>>(*this);
        
        return newStructPtr;
    }

    void printDerived(std::ostream& out) const override {
        printElement(out, element);
    }

    T element;    
};

void printElement(std::ostream& out, const Structure& s){
    s.print(out);
}
```

The problem is, for `==`, it has a structure in the function argument. This approach does not work, because when I pass this as an argument down to the `Element` class, it is still a `Structure` and not an `Element`.

Right now, my code works for every test case, except for the case of nested structures. When I try to compare two structures with other structures in them, I get this error:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==26776==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000104fbffb8 (pc 0x00010423ec88 bp 0x00010423ec64 sp 0x00016bbc79d0 T0)
==26776==The signal is caused by a UNKNOWN memory access.
```

Why is my code resulting in this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem - your `operator=` is implemented wrong. It is returning `*this` *by value*, but it needs to return it *by reference* instead. And, you need to call `elements.clear()` *unconditionally*, otherwise you will be **appending** elements instead of **replacing** elements when `Structure x` of `n` number of elements is assigned to `Structure y` that also has `n` elements.
Remy Lebe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator==` is doing the right thing by using a virtual `equals()` method, however the rest of it is not implemented correctly.  You are treating the `result` variable the wrong way, and worse the code has *undefined behavior* if the two vectors have different sizes.  Try this instead:

```
class Structure{
public:
    ...
    bool operator == (const Structure& other) const {
        if (elements.size() != other.elements.size())
            return false;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < other.elements.size(); ++i) {
            if (!elements[i]->equals(*(other.elements[i])))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    ...
};
```

Now, that being said, you can't make `Element::equals()` accept an `Element` when you are calling it polymorphically from `Structure`, like you are asking for (at least, not without casting).

But, what you can do (and need to do) is make `Element::equals()` check if the input `Structure` is actually an `Element` or not.  You have to do that anyway so that you can differentiate between `Element<X>` and `Element<Y>` when `X` and `Y` are different types.  The way you are using `static_cast` is not doing that validation, so you will have *undefined behavior* when you cast to the wrong type.  And you can't do the check with `std::is_same_v` (a compile-time check), either.  You *must* use `dynamic_cast` (a runtime check), eg:

```
template<class T>
class Element : public Structure{
public:
    ...
    bool equals (const Structure& otherStruct) const override {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Structure>){
            return element == otherStruct; 
        }
        else {
            auto other = dynamic_cast<const Element<T>*>(&otherStruct);
            return (other && element == other->element);
        }
    }
    ...
};
```

However, since you say you can't use `dynamic_cast` (why?), you will just have to *tag every* `Element` based on which `T` it is created with, and then you can compare the tags for equality before casting, eg:

```
#include <typeinfo>

template<class T>
class Element : public Structure{
public:
    ...
    const std::type_info& getTypeInfo() const {
        return typeid(T);
    }
    
    bool equals (const Structure& otherStruct) const override {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Structure>){
            return element == otherStruct; 
        }
        else if (getTypeInfo() == otherStruct.getTypeInfo()) {
            return element == static_cast<const Element<T>&>(otherStruct).element;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: ok I am trying to use the second method you have shown but I am getting this error: ```error: use of typeid requires -frtti```.    any idea what this means and how to fix it? I have ```#include <typeinfo>```

Comment: @callumarul as the error says, invoke the compiler with the `-frtti` switch enabled to generate RTTI (Runtime Type Information) during compiling. Refer to your compiler's documentation to see how to do that. The alternative is to write extra code to manually translate `T` into an enum value and then compare those values. Or, use `std::variant`. However, either of those approaches will restrict the number of data types you can support (which is not necessarily a bad thing).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is has been super helpful!